# Elements of a given order in finite cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

List all elements of order $4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_8=\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$.

Also list all the elements of order $6$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{72}=\mathbb{Z}/72\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What do you know in general about the subgroups of a cyclic group?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** List *all* elements of $\Bbb Z_8$, then write up the order of each:
$$\Bbb Z_8=\{0,1,2,3,4,-3,-2,-1\}\,,$$
as $-x$ represents the same equivalence class as $8-x$ modulo $8$. I guess, we are talking about *additive* order, that is, the question is for each $x\in\Bbb Z_8$, what is the least $n>0$, such that $n\cdot x=0$ (modulo $8$, of course).

Comment: +1 for my friend Berci and for theoretical solid approach.

Answer (score 1):

I did your problem by using GAP, however, it is strongly suggested that you do the Group theory exercises by hand. 
[image]